# Не загружаются скрипты и ресурсы, находящиеся в jar модуле

Tags: java, webview, javafx, resources

**Дано:**
Многомодульное JavaFX + Groovy + Java приложение. GUI сделан на связке JavaFX + Groovy + WebView, часть контролов представляет из себя html страницу + jquery + кастомные js скрипты, т.е. для контрола создаем WebView, загружаем в него html, который в свою очередь использует js+css и радуемся жизни.

**Проблема:**
На практике, все это очень хорошо, и если запускаться из IDEA или, допустим, "из gradle", то все хорошо запускается и работает. Но как только мы собираем приложение (в данный момент это нативное windows приложение), то загрузка скриптов внутри html перестает работать, хотя html, js, css, и т.п. файлы ресурсов вкомпиливаются в jarники модулей.
Причем отваливается только загрузка внутри html и только для локальных ресурсов.

Собственно, хочется победить этот момент, пусть даже изменив структуру программы, буду рад любой помощи и советам.

Comment: Удалось найти такое решение https://github.com/dahuapp/dahu/blob/760f5a69111b480e963316c623717dd416a4f86c/editor/src/main/java/io/dahuapp/editor/app/DahuApp.java#L117-L140 проблемы.